# Recursively calculate records within a time interval in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table where records will be getting inserted every 4 hours on a daily basis. If the record was not inserted for continuous 4 hours, I need to insert a log into another table. Below is the table schema.

```
Id           DocPathid          CreatedAt
1                1              2021-04-02 00:00:00
2                1              2021-04-02 04:00:00
3                1              2021-04-02 09:00:00
4                1              2021-04-02 12:00:00  
5                1              2021-04-02 16:00:00  
6                1              2021-04-02 20:00:00 
7                1              2021-04-02 24:00:00
```

In the above case, there was no records inserted within a interval of 4hours (i.e. between `2021-04-02 04:00:00` & `2021-04-02 09:00:00`). The query should return no. of failure count (in this case it is failed for 1 time).

Is there a way to achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
   select count(1)
    from (
      select id, CreatedAt , timestampdiff(hour, CreatedAt  
                 , lead(CreatedAt,1) over (partition by DocPathid order by CreatedAt) ) as hour 
      from Table1  
      ) t
      where hour >4
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b0c631145422dbccd2ea23f0a7d2011

Comment: It says "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: datediff was a sqlserver function. You need to use timestampdiff for mysql if you want in hour.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html